# How to build Ionic for Windows UAP?

Tags: ionic2, windows-10-universal, cordova-win10

When I run ,

```
ionic build windows
```

in command prompt, it says Windows Phone SDK 8.1 is not found. In case I'm trying to build for Windows UAP, do I still need SDK 8.1? I have Windows SDK 10.0 along with Visual Studio 2015 installed. I'm working on a Windows 64-bit platform.

[image: Error: Windows Phone SDK 8.1 not found]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First and foremost thing after you create a new app, you would need to add a platform.

```
ionic platform add windows
```

And as for windows, I think it defaults to win 8.1/8. So, naturally it would search for windows 8.1 SDK. At this point you could tweak the config.xml file (present in the root of your app, not elsewhere) by adding these lines to it, as a child of the `<widget/>` tag.

```
<platform name="windows">
    <preference name="windows-target-version" value="10.0" />
</platform>
```

Then you should run

```
ionic build windows
```

for the changes to take effect.
And then running

```
cordova requirements
```

would show you that all the requirements are met.

[image: ionic build windows executes without error]